# Is there some way i can pass the variable expression in @RequestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am passing the key through the url which changes every time on the basis of previous page. I have to open the same page on the basis of different key. So is there a way to pass the variable in request maapping attribute or some other option is also available?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email?key="+inviteEmailEncrypted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a param with the @RequestParam annotation to your method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email")
public void daMethod(@RequestParam("key") String inviteEmailEncrypted) {
    System.out.println("The key is = " + inviteEmailEncrypted);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to invoke the @RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email") when i open the http://localhost:8090/QuickStartConsulting/quickstart/email?key=d5 is accesed .the value of key is defined in another method and that i cannot get the key value since the jsp related to that method is not attached to emaillogin jsp

Answer (score 2):

If your page change in base of `inviteEmailEncrypted`u can use `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/quickstart/email")
public ModelAndView method(@RequestParam("key") String inviteEmailEncrypted)
```

Then you can use `inviteEmailEncrypted` as a normal method input parameter and do whatever you want with it.
Docs: [Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestparam)